# Alternative spell system

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I am looking for a spell system (preferably one that can use the existing spell lists) that operates based on Mana/Spell Points rather than the Vancian system. I am already familiar with the Unearthed Arcana one and the one found [here](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SP_Spellcasting_%283.5e_Variant_Rule%29). I am also looking for balancing in this system, and unless the system introduces new classes, I would like to stick to core classes.

Comment: Why aren't you using the spell point system which already exists? It's important to know since it indicates there's another requirement which that system doesn't fulfil.

Comment: Hey @Garan.  Here on RPG.SE we look for questions with a single best answer and frown on "list questions."  Normally you'd provide more details of what exactly you're looking for in a spell system so that people can match things they've used against that.  Just asking "for systems" will get you the literally dozens of spell systems people crapped out for D&D 3.5 over the years.  Please edit in more requirements and I'll reopen.

Answer (score 5):

**Psionic Mechanics, Arcane Flavor**

You can try a converted psionics spellcasting system, more detail in a full thread [here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=194002k)

Quoting the author:

> It includes a complete conversion of the psionic base system, feats and fundamental items over to magical terminology, as well as, more importantly, translated classes to utilize the mechanics, and a relatively thorough conversion of the Sorcerer/Wizard, Cleric, Bard, Paladin, Assassin and Blackguard lists over to what 3.5 fans know as psionic mechanics. For the classes presented so far, it should be playable from 1-20.

And here the main difference from this variant from another:

> The primary difference between this project and every other spell point variant I have seen is simple - I rewrote the spells so that they take the system into account. No other spell point system I have seen has done this.
>   In addition, this isn't really a new spell point system. This is the well known and researched psionic system, which we all know works. I just added a paint job and a new bell or two.

Comment: The conversion by @Ernir is excellent, and I **strongly** recommend it. There are mirrors for it available, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a Mana magic system, your first try may be the [Unearthed Arcana spell points variant](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/magic/spellPoints.htm) (the same one that you mentioned in your question).

The core problem with it is, *ahem*, wizard. With spell points variant he

- has just a little bit casting capability than a sorcerer.
- has much more versatility.
- still has to memorize spells per day to define his repertoire for the day, so the Vancian magic remains right here.

If wizard could cast anything from his spellbook but had mana on par that of a bard, these problems could be circumvented. I don't say that is an ideal fix, though.

Note (just a nitpick): as written, magic items do not change bonus spell points for high spellcasting attribute.

The second [variant](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SP_Spellcasting_%283.5e_Variant_Rule%29) you mention is not a complete spellcasting variant in any case - one still have to assign point cost to the actual spells - and is probably designed with creation of the new classes in mind.

You could also try to take *Spell-to-power Erudite* casting mechanic for wizards.

Comment: That link was a mistake, was supposed to be to http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SP_Spellcasting_%283.5e_Variant_Rule%29 (also fixed it in post)